# node-opcua client cannot connect to ignition endpoint. Client connection rejected by Ignition OPC-UA server

Tags: client, opc-ua, node-opcua, ignition

Ignition server security policy is Basic256Sha256.
node-opcua client options:

```
const client = OPCUAClient.create({
    endpointMustExist: false,
    securityMode: MessageSecurityMode.SignAndEncrypt,
    securityPolicy: SecurityPolicy.Basic256Sha256,
  });
```

session is created with a username and password:

```
   let userIdentity = {
        userName: "thisisnottheusername",
        password: "thisisnotthepassword",
      };

   function (callback) {
      client.createSession(userIdentity, function (err, session) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }
        the_session = session;
        callback();
      });
      }
```

The error I am getting is below:

```
 cannot connect to endpoint : opc.tcp://localhost:62541
 failure  Error: The connection may have been rejected by server,
Err = (_socket has been disconnected by third party)
    at C:\Users\WilliamGibson\node_modules\node-opcua-client\dist\private\client_base_impl.js:704:27
    at C:\Users\WilliamGibson\node_modules\node-opcua-client\dist\private\client_base_impl.js:504:17
    at C:\Users\WilliamGibson\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3681:19
    at wrapper (C:\Users\WilliamGibson\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:271:20)
    at iterateeCallback (C:\Users\WilliamGibson\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:419:21)
    at C:\Users\WilliamGibson\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:327:20
    at C:\Users\WilliamGibson\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3679:17
    at C:\Users\WilliamGibson\node_modules\node-opcua-client\dist\private\client_base_impl.js:474:21
    at ClientSecureChannelLayer.<anonymous> (C:\Users\WilliamGibson\node_modules\node-opcua-secure-channel\dist\source\client\client_secure_channel_layer.js:727:13)
```

I am using node-opcua's sample_client.js as a basis for my OPC-UA client. 
I'm not sure what is going wrong, so any help is appreciated!